# Unable to run python code on shinyapps.io

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, shinyapps

Hello I am deploying a shiny dashboard on shinyapps.io which is sourcing a python script. However, I am running to error when the script runs on shinyapps.io but it runs locally. I understand the reason could be that locally I am running on windows and shinyapps.io runs on ubuntu.

Now I have never worked on unbuntu so I am not sure what could be the problem and how it fix it, below is the code for which I am getting the error

```py
df1_map = results.set_index('time_elapsed')['delta_retention'].to_dict()
frame_shot['cum_delta_retention'] = frame_shot.apply(lambda x: ([f'{v:.6f}'.format(v=v) for k, v in df1_map.items() if k >= x.Start and k <= x.End]), axis=1)
```

Below is the error that I am getting

```
Warning: Error in py_run_file_impl: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 182)
```

I was hoping if someone can help me understand if this can be run on ubuntu or how can it be fixed.

Thanks a lot in advance !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax only works for python >=3.7

```
f'{v:.6f}'
```

Otherwise use >=2.7

```
'{v:.6f}'.format(v=v)
```

I would check this.

Comment: @Chrimson, I tried this and it doesnt seems to be working. I am still getting the same syntax error. Here is what I updated it to `frame_shot.apply(lambda x: ([f'{v:.6f}'.format(v=v) for k, v in df1_map.items() if k >= x.Start and k <= x.End]), axis=1)`

Comment: @Chrimson, I have just updated the code to give you more reference

Comment: @Chrimson,My bad, I missed the `.` after the colons. This seems to have fixed the error. Thanks a lot for the response.